# Forest plot: Visualization original confidence interval of individual studies but weighting in pooling estimate

Tags: r, metafor

I want to visualize original confidence interval of individual studies in forest plot; however, weighting will be used to create pooled estimate.

I used weighted=FALSE.
My code

```
res <- rma(lnhr, sei=se, data=dffc, method="REML", test="knha", weighted = FALSE)
res

par(mar = c(6, 6, 3, 3))
forest(res, addpred = FALSE, annotate= TRUE, at=seq(0,8,by=1),  
       order= dffc$exo,
       showweights=TRUE,
       ilab=cbind(expo, com), ilab.xpos=c(-3, -1.5), mlab = "", xlab= " ",
       cex=1.1, xlim=c(8, 4), alim = c(-6, 6),  
       transf=transf.exp.int,
       refline=1,
       slab=paste(dffc$author)
)
```

My plot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IE2Nz.png)

So, it is **unweighted pooled estimate; visualization of confindence interval of individual studies shows weighted confidence interval.
**

However, I want opposite. **Weighted pooled estimate and unweighted confidence interval of individual studies.**

Comment: There is no such thing as a 'weighted confidence interval of the individual studies', so just leave `weighted=TRUE` (i.e., the default) and you are getting a weighted pooled estimate and the standard CIs of the individual studies.

Comment: Thank you @Wolfgang for your comment. Why 'weighted=FALSE' is also giving weighted Cls in individual studies in the plot? However, unweighted pooled estimate.   Am I making any mistakes in the code?

Comment: What is a 'weighted CI'? There is no such thing, so it cannot give something that doesn't exist. Like I said, just use `weighted=TRUE`. It will give you the weighted pooled estimate like you want.

Comment: Sorry @Wolfgang. I mean that in forest plot CI of individual studies has been changed compared to the reported CI of individual studies. How can I show reported CI in forest plot? thank you.

Comment: Please provide a fully reproducible example illustrating the issue. Without this, it is not possible to help.